# bash: extraction of substrings by pattern, empty fields and multiple occurrences

Tags: regex, bash, awk, extract

I would like to extract the `Pfam_A` information from each line of a file:

```
item_1    ID=HJNANFJJ_180142;inference=ab initio prediction:Prodigal_v2.6.3;locus_tag=HJNANFJJ_180142;partial=01;product=unannotated protein;KEGG=K03531
item_4    ID=HJNANFJJ_87662;inference=ab initio prediction:Prodigal_v2.6.3;locus_tag=HJNANFJJ_87662;partial=10;product=unannotated protein;KEGG=K15725;Pfam_A=OEP;Resfams=adeC-adeK-oprM
item_8    ID=HJNANFJJ_328505;inference=ab initio prediction:Prodigal_v2.6.3;locus_tag=HJNANFJJ_328505;partial=11;product=unannotated protein;KEGG=K03578;Pfam_A=OB_NTP_bind    
item_2    ID=HJNANFJJ_512995;inference=ab initio prediction:Prodigal_v2.6.3;locus_tag=HJNANFJJ_512995;partial=11;product=unannotated protein;KEGG=K00674;Pfam_A=Hexapep;Pfam_A=Hexapep_2;metacyc=TETHYDPICSUCC-RXN
item_0    ID=HJNANFJJ_188729;inference=ab initio prediction:Prodigal_v2.6.3;locus_tag=HJNANFJJ_188729;partial=11;product=unannotated protein
```

In some lines this information is missing at all, in some there can be multiple occurrences.

Finally, I want to get a table like this, so that instead of empty fields there is `NaN` and multiple occurrences are put tab separated into different fields:

```
item_1    NaN
item_4    OEP
item_8    OB_NTP_bind    
item_2    Hexapep    Hexapep_2
item_0    NaN
```

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: Can a field following the `Pfam_A=` contain space characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' 'NF > 1 {
   s = ""
   n = split($NF, a, /;/)
   for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
      if (split(a[i], b, /=/) == 2 && b[1] == "Pfam_A")
         s = s OFS b[2]
   print $1 (s ? s : OFS "NaN")
}' file
```

```
item_1  NaN
item_4  OEP
item_8  OB_NTP_bind
item_2  Hexapep Hexapep_2
item_0  NaN
```

Comment: This will not work for a line as
`item_x    ID=XXX;Pfam_A=Hexapep;product=unannotated protein`

Comment: It is because your input is wrong. OP is picking up `Pfam_A` values from last field only.

Comment: No. There are two lines in the OP's input that `Pfam_A` is not the last field. If the fields following `Pfam_A` contain space characters then your code will not work.

Comment: You are making an assumption that you should clarify with OP rather than debating here. My answer matched with expected output of OP btw

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way would be:

```
awk '{ s=$0;t="";
    while (match(s,"Pfam_A=[^;]*")) {
       t = t (t?OFS:"") substr(s,RSTART+7,RLENGTH-7);
       s = substr(s,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}{print $1, (t?t:"NaN")}' file
```

Comment: For `item_2` OP expects multiple values

Answer (score 0):

With the presumptions that in each input line, there are no other `;` characters except for the `;` characters that separate the data fields, and no tab characters unless they delimit the first column, a simple `sed` command could do the job:

```
sed -E 's/\s+/;/; s/;Pfam_A=/;\t/g; s/;[^\t]*//g; /\t/!s/$/\tNaN/' file
```